# Cannot scroll up after .animate scrollTop

Tags: jquery

```
var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $('#header');
var offset1 = $('#boxes').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scroll_start < offset1) {
       $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($('#boxes').offset()).top - 50
        }, 2500)
    } else if(scroll_start > offset1) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

I am new to coding jquery and I want to apply smooth scrolling to divs. This code seems to work at one point but the scroll gets stuck when it already reaches the #boxes div. (The else if is not working) I want some way to be able to scroll freely after the animation. Some explanations would be really helpful thanks!

Comment: Seeing your HTML would help a lot

Comment: Are you intentionally ignoring the case where `scroll_start = offset1`? Not that it seems to relate, just curious.

Comment: sorry im quite new to stack overflow I tried making it >= to offset1 but it still doesnt work.

Comment: I just want a way to navigate through divs with smooth scrolling any kind of help would be appreciated